# Ansible Preferred Way Of Running An Ad Hoc Command

Tags: ansible

I'm pretty new to Ansible, just a day old and while trying out some basic ad hoc commands, I noticed that in order to create a directory on a group named *nodes*, both of the following commands worked.

METHOD 1

```
ansible nodes -a "mkdir /BYANSIBLE_2"
```

METHOD 2

```
ansible nodes -m file -a "path=/BYANSIBLE_3 state=touch"
```

According to the documentation, -a means module arguments, so why does METHOD 1 work ?
According to my understanding merely providing the arguments of a module without specifying the module itself shouldn't work (unless there is some implicit default).

[image]

Also, as a newbie, should I focus on METHOD 1 or METHOD 2 when using adhoc commands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible uses the module ansible.builtin.command by default if no module is provided in the command line . This module just runs commands on the remote nodes command line, which is why "mkdir path" works. for you. The argument for this module is, well, a command.

On method 2 you are actually calling a specific module "file" that has its own definition of the arguments required. The argument for this module is just the path that needs to be created.

The method that you use depend on the case. If you are testing commands on remote nodes, method 1 would be my go to, since is faster than explicitly adding the module name. Method 2 is better in the sense that is more explicit in intention.

But more importantly, i try to keep ad hoc commands for very small tests and tasks. Ansible is about automating and scaling to me, so i try to create playbooks whenever possible.

You can read more in the following link:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html